# In time/times of war

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do I have to use time of times in the following sentence?

'This mood is created by the fragments of which the setting is a place in times/time of war'

Comment: Are you talking about fragments of writing set in a particular place? If so, it depends whether the setting is during one particular war or several different ones.

Comment: Hi, I am talking about fragments of a video (https://youtu.be/A0FiASkiD6M). Multiple fragments have the setting 'a place in time(s) of war.

Comment: These are obviously clips from _different_ times/places, so I would say '...of which the _settings are_ places in time of war.'